# JS Regex replacement - replace fixed text around random string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this text:

```
<span class='green'>foobar</span> something <span class='red'>fizzle</span>
```

I need to somehow attain this:

```
<tagA>foobar</tagA> something <tabB>fizzle</tagB>
```

I basically have to match `<span class='green'>*anything*</span>` and be able to differentiate it from the red one as well. I have to take this green span on both ends and replace it with a fixed string, but somehow retain whatever text is between the two tags.

I swear I've looked around a ton but have no idea how to find the solution for this with regex.

Comment: Don't use Regex for HTML tags, And what about `<span class='green'><span class='green'>foo</span>foobar<span class='green'>bar</span></span>` ? ;).

Comment: It's not for HTML - it's for something else, I'm abstracting the concept so I can explain it easier.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

Replace

```
<span class='green'>(.*?)</span>
```

With

```
<tagA>$1</tagA>
```

And do something similar for the class with the value red

**Update 1**

Response to feedback "What if something contains a newline?"

If I remember correctly JavaScript does not support the "single line mode" / Dot matches line breaks.

```
<span class='green'>([\s\S]*?)</span>
```

**Update 2**

This tweaked regex allows

```
<span\s+class\s*=\s*['"]green['"]\s*>([^>]*)</\s*span\s*>
```

- white space where the html spec is allowing it
- accepts single as well as double quotes for the attribute values
- matches the value between the tags using a negated character class which is qualified greedy resulting in better performance generally and is also supported by JavaScript

Comment: This looked like it worked - thanks! Simpler than I thought.

Comment: What if `something` contains a newline?

Comment: Ok, the only remaining issue is nested tag groups - if there are any. Let OP decide.

Comment: @stribizhev  As you know you can get clever with regexes and maybe support nested groups but If this support is needed I would switch to a HTML parsing library.